# Android: change button color programmatically with defined drawable

Tags: android

I have:

```
public Button[] getButtons(int buttonCount, List<String> buttonHeaders, Context activity) {
    Button[] result = new Button[buttonCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < buttonCount; i++) {

        result[i] = new Button(activity);

        result[i].setId(i);
        result[i].setText(buttonHeaders.get(i));
        result[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttons_shape);
        result[i].setBackgroundColor(randomColor(activity));
        result[i].setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        result[i].setWidth(360);
        result[i].setHeight(100);
    }
    return result;
}
```

but in my drawable is:

```
 <solid android:color="@color/white"/> 
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
```

but I would like to define the program what color, because the Color are random, and when i change background is return to the default design (PS. Sorry for English :P)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do both.. either you can do view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable); or view.setBackGroundColor(color);

Comment: Yes when i use setBackgroundDrawable(drawable) is set my own style, but when later i want change color with setBackgroundColor it return default style and set only color without rounded corner

Comment: That is because the style belongs to drawable and not to your view.. so, calling setBackGroundColor removes the backgroundDrawable.

Comment: then how to fix this?

Comment: One thing that you can do is, have two drawables of same style but different colors and call view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable); instead of calling view.setBackgroundColor(color);

Comment: and second? because i have about 20 diffrent colors :/

Comment: Then probably, you need to develop a smart algorithm that intakes a transparent bitmap (or of your choice), gives it to canvas and add a colored layer onto it dynamically, and then set it as drawable of your view.